# Multi-panel titles in R

Tags: r, plot

I have an ultra short question about R

My aim is to assign a common title to a multi-panel plot generated using par, e.g.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(rnorm(1000))
plot(rnorm(1000))
```

So, something like "main" for the plot function, but extended to both plots. Is there a canonical way to do this?

Thanks for any answer :-)

Comment: What a coincidence, I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241184/overall-title-for-plotting-window today morning.

Comment: That's also a solution, and yeah I should use Rlattice more often.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `mtext` with option `outer`:

```
set.seed(42)
oldpar <- par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(3,3,1,1), oma=c(0,0,3,1))  ## oma creates space 
plot(cumsum(rnorm(100)), type='l', main="Plot A")
plot(cumsum(rnorm(100)), type='l', main="Plot B")
mtext("Now isn't this random", side=3, line=1, outer=TRUE, cex=2, font=2)
par(oldpar)
```

Comment: If only my wife said that more often.

Comment: eddelbuettel Your wife doesn't appreciate "multi-panel titles"?

Comment: Must. Not. Comment. Any. Further. ;-)